# How can I learn more about how type checking happens in Idris?

Tags: idris, typechecking, dependent-type

I am learning programming using dependent types and started using Idris recently. I have some background in programming languages and understand how type checking happens in languages like Haskell and ML. I wanted to know if there is some description of how type checking happens in Idris, even a flag that can be passed to the Idris compiler which dumps the output of the type checker will also be useful.

For example, I want to understand how Idris type checks the correctness of the function append,

```
append : Vect m elem -> Vect n elem -> Vect (m + n) elem
append [] ys = ys
append (x::xs) ys = x :: (append xs ys)
```

The reason is that Idris gives a type error when I wrongly define append as `append (x::xs) ys = x :: (append ys xs)`, I interchanged the arguments in the recursive call, saying that (plus k n) is not equal to (plus n k). 
My guess is that even if I fix this by giving a proof that plus is commutative, Idris must still give a type error. Therefore, I want to understand type checking in Idris and see if it really happens and if so how it figures out. Thanks in advance.